# How to highlight on words of content editable area text without affecting its structure like paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Am creating a simple spelling correction website but I have managed to deal with the backend and I can get suggestions for a specific word but the main problem is the frontend.
I want to borrow the idea of https://languagetool.org/ of highlighting the word that has been spelled wrongly by adding a floating div with a bottom border, transparent color, and negative z-index by finding the position of the word in text

```js
var editor = document.querySelector("#sp-editor");

var myrange;
$(".sp-editor").click(function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX - 30;
    var y = e.clientY - 15;
    $("#slp-dropdown").attr("style", "margin-left: " + x + "px; margin-top: " + y + "px");
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (!selection || selection.rangeCount < 1) return true;
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var node = selection.anchorNode;
    var word_regexp = /^\w*$/;
    // Extend the range backward until it matches word beginning
    while ((range.startOffset > 0) && range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
    }
    // Restore the valid word match after overshooting
    if (!range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
    }

    // Extend the range forward until it matches word ending
    while ((range.endOffset < node.length) && range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);
    }
    // Restore the valid word match after overshooting
    if (!range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset - 1);
    }
    var word = range.toString();
    checkClickedWord(word, range);
});

function changeTextNode(word) {
    myrange.deleteContents();
    myrange.insertNode(document.createTextNode(word));
    $("#slp-dropdown").hide();
}

function checkClickedWord(word, range) {
    if (word.length > 0) {
        $("#slp-dropdown").show();
        myrange = range;
    }
}
```

```css
.sp-editor{
        height: 260px;
    }
    /* Style The Dropdown Button */
    .word {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .word.underline{
        border-bottom: 2px solid #3e8e41;
    }
    
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }

    .underline-text{
        position: absolute;
        width: 160px;
        height: 30px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #3e8e41;
        background-color: rgba(19, 180, 54, 0.2);
        z-index: -99;
    }
    
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .word-list {
        display: cancle;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .word-list a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    .word-list a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    .dropdown:hover .word-list {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui" name="viewport">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="spelling.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="updating-indicator"></div><br>
<div class="sp-editor-wrapper">
  <!--DROPDOWNstyle="margin-left: 385px; margin-top: 68px"-->
  <div id="slp-dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <div class="word-list">
      <a onclick="changeTextNode('world')" class="item-word" href="#">world</a>
      <a onclick="changeTextNode('word')" class="item-word" href="#">word</a>
      <a onclick="changeTextNode('wood')" class="item-word" href="#">wood</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- <div id="underline-text" style="margin-left: 385px; margin-top: 30px" class="underline-text"></div> -->
    <!--DROPDOWN-->
<div id="sp-editor" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapiatlise="off" spellcheck="false" class="sp-editor">
The Project Gutenberg eBook of Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll<br>
<br>
This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere in the United States and
most other parts of the world at no costs and with almost no restrections
whatsoever. You may copy it, give it away or re-use it under the terms
of the Project Gutenberg License included with this eBook or online at
www.gutenberg.org. If you are not lokated in the United States, you
will have to check the laws of the country where you are located before
using this eBook.
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.
I have managed to handle replacing of words in the text in this JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lh3bxuo7/1/ that have been clicked on by the user but I need to find a way of highlighting target words in the text without affecting the paragraph and new lines and check if the clicked word is in the list of the marked words that are have been spelled wrongly like var `wrongwords = ["restrections", "lokated"]` and are supposed to be marked in text

Comment: Enclosing the target word(s) in a `<span class="something">` shouldn't affect newlines or wrapping as long as the styles you apply to `class="something"` don't change the text size or spacing (e.g. no bold, no font-size)

Comment: if I get plain text from the text area then I split the text according to spaces and how can I wrap the span tags to the words i have wrongly spelled if I store them in an array and use their respective index as a unique id in the entire corpus. please if can provide me js code that wraps the span tags